# File Encryption And Decryption In Java, doesn't work decryption

Tags: java, file, encryption, des

Hi guys I have to do this and I can encrypt file according to the des algorithm but I can not decyrpt again file  ,I recieve error messaje like that :

javax.crypto.BadPaddingException Given final block not properly padded

I can not decrypt file I couldnt find  why. Can u help me please 
Thank you guys.

JAVA CODE :

```
public class Sifreleme {

    public static void encrypt(){
     try {
            SecretKey key = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES").generateKey();

            FileOutputStream fosKey = new FileOutputStream("..\\KEY");
            SecretKeyFactory keyfac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
            DESKeySpec keyspec = (DESKeySpec) keyfac.getKeySpec(key, DESKeySpec.class);
            fosKey.write(keyspec.getKey());
            fosKey.close();

            Cipher crypt = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
            crypt.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\akif\\Desktop\\zilsesi.mp3");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\akif\\Desktop\\sifrelenenzilsesi.mp3");
            byte[] arrayBytes = new byte[8];
            int bytesReads;
            while ((bytesReads = fis.read(arrayBytes)) != -1) {
                fos.write(crypt.doFinal(arrayBytes), 0, bytesReads);
            }
            fis.close();
            fos.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }




public static void decrypt(){
       try {
                FileInputStream fisKey = new FileInputStream("..\\KEY");
                byte[] arrayKey = new byte[fisKey.available()];
                fisKey.read(arrayKey);
                SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(arrayKey, "DES");

                Cipher decrypt = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
                decrypt.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\akif\\Desktop\\sifrelenenzilsesi.mp3");
                byte[] encText = new byte[16];
                int bytesReads;
                while ((bytesReads = fis.read(encText)) != -1) {
                    fis.read(decrypt.doFinal(encText), 0, bytesReads);
                }
                fis.close();
                System.out.println(new String(encText));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public static void main(String []args) throws IOException{
        encrypt();
        decrypt();
        }
```

Comment: You are calling ``decrypt.doFinal(encText)`` before reading all of the bytes from the file. Read all bytes, then pass them to the decrypter.

Comment: Do I need to use decrypt.update(enctext) ? because I didnt understand this dofinal code line , Where will I use at ?

Answer (score 2):

Your code here:

```
    while ((bytesReads = fis.read(encText)) != -1) {
        fis.read(decrypt.doFinal(encText), 0, bytesReads);
    }
```

Is rather obviously wrong: you need to write the plaintext generated by calling `decrypt.doFinal` just like you do during encryption. Currently you are overwriting the generated plaintext by the next block(s) of ciphertext because you call `read` twice in the loop.

Furthermore, depending on your DES `Cipher` implementation, you forgot about the IV.

---

A lot of other things are wrong as well, including:

- the stream handling using `getAvailable()`;
- the use of the 56 bit DES cipher;
- the use of ECB mode;
- the repeated calls to `doFinal` (which results in a very large overhead and insecure code);
- not using the `CipherInputStream` and `CipherOutputStream` (etcetera);
- using a string as the key;
- forgetting to close your streams when an exception occurs (use the `try` with resources);
- the `printStackTracke()` exception handling;
- the use of `static` fields as variables.

Using the platform encoding within `new String(encText)` is only likely wrong.

---

Note that using the wrong key / ciphertext combination will likely also result in this error.

Comment: Sorry, I'm used to perform code reviews now and then :P